# get a variable from the scope where the function used not Global

Tags: php, global

how to access the variable X in Function Func1 not in global Scope

```
$X='hi';

function Func1(){
     global $X;
     echo $X;
   }
function Func2(){
     $X='hello';
     Func1();    // I want to echo "hello" not "hi"
   }
```

Comment: This is why you should pass arguments to functions when you call them, and not simply use global as a solution to every scope issue

Answer (score 0):

(First of all, good job trying to avoid using a global. They are almost never the right answer.)

Variables in PHP functions are locally scoped - they don't inherit anything from where they're called. Func1 has no idea about any variables or anything else that happens in Func2, it only knows about itself.

If you want a variable available in a function, then you need to pass it in as an argument:

```
function Func1($X){
  echo $X;
}

function Func2(){
  $X='hello';
  Func1($X);
}
```

It would be worth reading http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php to get a basic grounding in scope in PHP.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to echo $x;
is there any way to use variable $x in func1() 
without passing it as parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
$x = 'hi';

function func1(){
   echo func2();
}

function func2(){
   return $x = 'hello';
}
```

The x variable will get overridden and the function will return the variable data.

Next, the func2 will be called in func1 and the returned value will be printed on the screen.

Just tried to minimize the number of lines.

Comment: No $x will not get overridden 
inside func2() its value will be 'hello'
and inside func1() there is no value of $x 
I need to pass $x into func1() from func2() 
without parameters and without returning it

Comment: Then there is only one way use oop method